# Shopping Cart Buy One is $15, buy two for 25. Only when buying groups of two does discount apply

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I would like a shopping cart rule that allows the customer to buy one product at regular price and the second one at $5 discount.  BUT I only want this to happen in groups of two.  For example: One is $15, two is $25, three is $40, four is $50, five is 65, six is $75, and so on.  These are simple products.  My current rule is set at a discount of 16.659% on all products which is making one $15, two $25, three $37.50, four $50, five $62.51, six $75.01, and so on.  Is there a way to do it the way I really want?

Rule I'm using is:

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :If total quantity  equals or greater than  2  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions:  SKU  is one of  TXTTS01,TXTTS02,TXTTS03,TXTTS0...
  .

Comment: That's what I initially thought, but unless I'm missing something, tier pricing is for the same product????  I want to use this across SKUs.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is Tier Pricing.  Refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-use-tier-pricing

Answer (score 0):

There are 3rd party extensions for Cross-Products tier stuff. In Magento even simples of a configurable have their own tier-counter.